# How to access an array in $_GET using JInput?

Tags: joomla-2.5, jinput, array

I've been researching different ways to get an array using JInput.

According to http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput there are 2 methods that I can use.

- Method1

  ```
  $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
  $jinput->get('nameOfArray',array(),'ARRAY');
  ```
- Method2

  ```
  $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
  $jinput->getArray('nameOfArray',array());
  ```

Note: `nameOfArray` is the name of the array I want to access in the $_GET superglobal array.

Method1 works, but Method2 gives the following error:

> Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to JInput::getArray() must be of the type array, string given, called in test.php

My question is: **What’s the difference between these two methods?**

- The array used in both examples is the same
- I'm using Joomla 2.5.x
- The array is a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first method looks for elements that start with the name that you have specified:

```
<input type="hidden" name="nameOfArray[test][1]" value="test" />
<input type="hidden" name="nameOfArray[]" value="test" />
<input type="hidden" name="nameOfArray[test][]" value="test" />
<input type="hidden" name="nameOfArray[tester][yes]" value="test" />
```

All of the above would be returned as part of an array in method one.

---

Method two does not attempt to load an array by name, instead it accepts an array and tries to find input elements to match the keys. Take the following input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="object1" value="test1" />
<input type="hidden" name="name2" value="test2" />
<input type="hidden" name="element3" value="test3" />
```

If you then did the following:

```
$elements = array('object1'=>'', 'name2'=>'', 'element3'=>'');
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$jinput->getArray($elements); // note that the second parameter is "datasource" not default value
```

You would then get an array as such in `$element`:

```
array('object1'=>'test1', 'name2'=>'test2', 'element3'=>'test3');
```

Comment: Yeap, and the documentation is wrong. I've made a change to it.